# How to solve .Net Framework Version Issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, clr

It works fine on server. But now I'm deploying this on new server. I just copied the Package from my old server to this server.

When I browse application, getting the below mentioned error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

On new Server its showing .net clr version v4.0.30319, but on old server it is
.net version v4.0.30319 for Application Pool.

Is this Framework related Issue? or m I missing something?

Comment: is your old server is the one where you are developing?

Comment: In your solution go to reference and right click and open properties of System.Web.WebPages.Razor  >> then set `COPY LOCAL = TRUE` and then deploy application again.. now application will take reference from your `bin folder` instead of default framework location.

Answer (score 0):

You new server might not have an ASP.NET-MVC installed on.  You can set the reference to `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` copied to local set to true.

Right click on the `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` in your references and click properties.  Set the `Copy Local` to true.

Comment: how to add reference to this assembly, its not showing when I try to add reference in Visual Studio.

Comment: if your project is asp.net-mvc-4.  it should be already referenced.  You dont need to add it again.